# Slow slicing of cp.array with index being zero dimensional cp.array (based on cp.argmin result)

Tags: cupy

I have some code, where I need to slice a larger cp.array based on the result of cp.argmin applied to a smaller cp.array. (See minimal code example below)

The problem is, that cp.argmin returns a zero dimensional cp.array, while slicing with the `:` operator apparently requires integer numbers.

```
import time
import cupy as cp

original = cp.empty((10000, 10000))
nrows, ncols = 1000, 1000
to_modify = cp.empty((nrows, ncols))
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    argmin = cp.argmin(to_modify)
    argmin = int(argmin)
    row_idx, col_idx = (argmin // ncols, argmin % ncols)
    sliced = original[row_idx : row_idx + nrows, col_idx : col_idx + ncols]
    to_modify += sliced

print(time.time() - start_time)
```

When I profile the code above (I use py-spy), the slowest line (~90% time) is the cast to int of argmin, but if I remove it, the line `sliced = original[ ... ]` becomes the slowest line, because the cast seems to be happening implicitely.
Is there a way to solve my problem in a performant way, circumventing the need for the `:` operator when slicing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find a viable solution using cupy.
Instead I started using numba. While numba requires more manual work in the form of writing cuda kernels, it also offers more control.
With numba.cuda.device_array(), numba.cuda.to_device() and numba.cuda.copy_to_host() one also has control over when the arrays are copied back and forth between cpu and gpu.
The hardest part was implementing argmin, which requires a reduce operation:

```
@cuda.jit
def find_argmin(data, argmin, tmp_min, tmp_idx):
    x = cuda.grid(1)

    shape_x, shape_y = data.shape[0], data.shape[1]
    num_items = shape_x * shape_y
    num_threads = tmp_min.shape[0]
    num_items_per_thread = num_items // num_threads

    min_val = data[0, 0]
    min_ix, min_iy = 0, 0

    for idx in range(num_items_per_thread):
        idx = x * num_items_per_thread + idx
        if idx < num_items:
            ix, iy = idx // shape_y, idx % shape_y
            current = data[ix, iy]
            if current < min_val:
                min_val = current
                min_ix = ix
                min_iy = iy

    tmp_idx[x, 0] = min_ix
    tmp_idx[x, 1] = min_iy
    tmp_min[x] = min_val

    cuda.syncthreads()

    # find minimum in temporary array
    if x == 0:
        min_val = tmp_min[0]
        min_x, min_y = tmp_idx[0, 0], tmp_idx[0, 1]

        for idx in range(num_threads):
            if tmp_min[idx] < min_val:
                min_val = tmp_min[idx]
                min_x, min_y = tmp_idx[idx, 0], tmp_idx[idx, 1]

    argmin[0] = min_x
    argmin[1] = min_y
```

The rest are straightforward elementwise operations.